# combine macro arguments with text

Tags: luatex

I have a macro where I need to combine one of it's arguments with text to form a string that is used in lua.

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\directlua{
    myfunc("#1 4")
}
```

if I call `\mymacro{alpha}` I need myfunc to receive `alpha4` and **not** `alpha 4`

any ideas?

Comment: It seems that one can do #14 and it will work. Seems a bit strange but I guess as long as one doesn't have more than 9 macro parameters it should be fine. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don’t think TeX supports more than 9 macro parameters anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\mymacro` is a standard TeX macro: it does not matter at all that it includes `\directlua`. As such, the standard rules for replacement of material apply. When you define `\mymacro` with `"#1 4"`, you are telling it to substitute in `#1`, then a blank space, then a `4`. So its entirely to be expected that the space appears in the output.

As was indicated in a comment, TeX only allows up to nine arguments to a macro (and indeed working with a macro with nine arguments is pretty awkward). As such, you should miss out the space here or write your definition such that you use additional lines to divide up concepts

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    myfunc(
     "%
       #1%
       4%
     "
     )
  }%
}
```

Comment: `#1\relax4` also works.